# PHP- Redirect user (different inputs)

Tags: php, html

I want to redirect a user based on his input, there is a similar post on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), but it doesn't help.

**So there is only one input field.**

- When the user type in **"a" ->** redirecting to site a
- When the user type in **"b" ->** redirecting to site b

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: _“there is a similar post on StackOverflow, but it doesn't help”_ - what doesn’t help is posting stuff like this, without explaining _how exactly_ it “didn’t help”. Please go read [ask] before you ask your next question.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will do that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="server.php" method="GET">
            <input type="text" name="param"/>
            <button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit">Post</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

server.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['param'])) {

    $url = '';
    if($_GET['param'] == 'a') {
        $url = 'https://web1.com';

    } elseif($_GET['param'] == 'b') {
        $url = 'https://web2.com';

    } else {
        die("Invalid input!!");
    }

    header("Location: $url");
}
```

Both index.html and server.php files should be in same directory. If you wish to use $_POST instead of $_GET, change `method` in the form to `POST`

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to redirect in PHP

```
<?php 
if($_GET['value'] == 'a')
{
  header("Location: https://web1.com"); 
  exit; 
}
else if($_GET['value'] == 'b')
{
  header("Location: https://web2.com"); 
  exit; 
}

?>
```

make sure your request in `GET` format if request is `POST` then use `$_POST`